# How to find last but one indexPath cell of table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I need to keep last but one indexPath cell of table view and compare it to the current one on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method.
I don't know how can I do it. I found answers about last cell selected, but it doesn't help me. If anybody has some solution, please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the reference of last indexPath in tableview add this code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(indexPath == _indexPathReference)
{
    //add your logic
}

...
...

if(indexPath.row == array.count - 1)
    _indexPathReference = indexPath;

return cell;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You try this out:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:<Pass_Last_But_One_Row> inSection:<Pass_Correct_Section>]
```

Here,

> Pass_Last_But_One_Row = cellDataModel.count - 1;